# How to “switch role” in aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm contracting for a company that has multiple aws accounts. They gave me access to the Login account and I "Switch Role" in the web console to the Project account I work on. In the web gui it works.

How do I do the same with `aws-cli`?? I only have access keys for the Login account and I don’t have permissions to create a user and access keys in the Project account. Is it even possible?

Comment: Docs: [Assuming an IAM Role in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html) & [AWS CLI Configuration Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Of course it's possible!

Let's assume you've got your *Login account* credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`, probably something like this:

```
~ $ cat ~/.aws/credentials
[customer-login]
aws_access_key_id = AKIABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQR
aws_secret_access_key = ZxCvBnMaSdFgHjKlQwErTyUiOp
```

All you need to do is to add another profile to `~/.aws/credentials` that will use the above profile to *switch account* to your project account role. You will also need the Project account *Role ARN* - you can find that in the web console in *IAM* -> *Roles* after you switch to the *Project account*. Let's say the Project account number is 123456789012...

```
[customer-project]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/your-project-role-name   # << Change this
source_profile = customer-login
```

With that in place you can test if it works:

```
~ $ aws --profile customer-project sts get-caller-identity
{
    "Account": "123456789012",
    "UserId": "AROA1B2C3D4E5F6G7H8I:botocore-session-1538120713",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/your-project-role-name/botocore-session-1538120713"
}
```

As you can see you're now in the Project account as confirmed by the Account id 123456789012.

If you want to always use this profile with `aws-cli` you can do so:

```
~ $ export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=customer-project
~ $ aws sts get-caller-identity
... will be the same output as above, even without specifying --profile ...
```

For more info check out this post: https://aws.nz/best-practice/cross-account-access-with-aws-cli/

Check also:

- [Assuming an IAM Role in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html).
- [AWS CLI Configuration Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html).

Comment: this requires `customer-project` role having a trust policy allowing `customer-login` to assumerole, yes?

Comment: Thanks, this worked, only I had to add ```source_profile = default``` to your answer, otherwise I got a *Partial credentials found in assume-role, missing: source_profile or credential_source* error

Comment: It worked for me. But If I have a lot of assume roles. It is not easy for me to remember all of it. It is pretty hard for me if MFA is required every time I assume role.
I already create a repo to make it easy. You can search and assume role which you want. It will cached your credentials and you can re-use befre It is expired - https://github.com/lamhaison/aws-cli-utils