# Unable to list services in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, containers

I'm setting up my first Kubernetes EKS cluster by following the [Getting Started guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) but I can't get past the step that verifies access with `kubectl get svc`. Instead of the list of services I'm getting:

```
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "svc"
```

I've got the `aws-iam-authenticator` in place, I've got the correct access and secret key for a user that has AWS Admin privileges, I checked everything I could think of yet can't figure out what's causing the error.

Comment: By any chance did you create the EKS cluster using *cross-account role*?

Comment: Yes I did. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you use `kubectl` with the **the exact same IAM User / Role** that you used to create the EKS cluster? Only *that* IAM User / Role is given `system:masters` privilege in Kubernetes. If you use a different role you'll see this error, even if that other role has Administrator permissions in its IAM Policy.

---

For example if you created the EKS cluster while logged in with **cross-account IAM Role** and now you're trying to use it with a *different IAM User* it won't work.

You can add more IAM users to EKS later but for start you'll have to use the IAM role that created the cluster. For example if you log into some *company-login* account and the *switch role* to *company-prod* account with role *Admin* you'll have to update the `kubeconfig` accordingly:

```
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:{company-prod-id}:cluster/{cluster-name}
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - cluster-name
      - -r                                          <<< Add this
      - arn:aws:iam::{company-prod-id}:role/Admin   <<< And this
      env:
      - name: AWS_PROFILE
        value: company-login-profile                <<< Must be your login account
```

Alternatively you can create a *cross-account profile* for **aws-cli** as described here: **[How to “switch role” in aws-cli?](https://serverfault.com/questions/933078/how-to-switch-role-in-aws-cli/933083#933083)** In that case you won't need the `-r arn:...:role/Admin` in `kubeconfig` as it's already done in `~/.aws/credentials`.

Once the role stuff is fixed you should be able to run `kubectl get svc`.

---

Once the above works you can [**Add more IAM Users and IAM Roles to EKS / Kubernetes**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html). I suggest you create a dedicated role like, e.g. `EKSAdmin` and require your IAM users to assume that in order to manage the cluster.

Hope that helps :)